# SQL - How to multiply a value in tandem with a range (EXCEL)

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I'm working with Excel's ODBC SQL driver to gather data from our ERP system.
The end goal is to have a Query that will return all the stockcodes from a range of BOM's, and multiply the QtyRequired field by the forecast value.

So, Select BOM#21, List all of the BOM's StockCodes & QtyRequired fields, then Multiply the UnitQtyRequired field by X and then do the same for the next item in the range.

Using this Command text I can retrieve the StockCodes from a Range of BOM's:

```
"SELECT Bom, StockCode, Description, QtyUnitRequired 
FROM dbo.InvMaster InvMaster, dbo.InvWarehouse InvWarehouse 
WHERE (Bom IN (" & strVals & "))"
```

I can't seem to find a solution to multiply the QtyUnitRequired result by the number next to each BOM. My range looks similar to this:

```
ex. BOM|QTY
  BOM21|100
  BOM66|150
  BOM12|75
```

I think I may need to change the approach and loop the query through each value instead but I'm not sure how to do this.

Any suggestions?